# Do PRNG need to be thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, random, prng

As long as concurrent calls don't cause seg-v's or return the same value, what reasons are there for preventing race conditions and data corruption in [PRNGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) when those error's primary effects are unpredictable results and that is the point of a PRNG?

---

*Edit:* are there any PRNG that wouldn't suffer under race conditions and data corruption?

Comment: Am I missing something or do you mean PRNG?

Comment: The english language: gotta love it.

Comment: @BCS - May as well fix the title while you're at it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PRNGs are meticulously constructed tools -- frankly, if race conditions and threading bugs were a good PRNG, the implementation would be written that way.

The problem with adding threading bugs to increase randomness is that it's an *unstudied* change to the generator. Existing secure algorithms and implementations have been exhaustively tested; if you want to try an unsafe variant, you'll need to do the statistical grunt work to show that it's at least as random as a normal PRNG.

Comment: I'm not referring to intentionally adding threading bugs, but not going out of your way to avoid them.

Comment: Fair enough -- but the effect will be the same if a bug sneaks in edgeways. ;) If you have the option of wrapping a static synchronized class around the PRNG's calls, that could be easiest. I really doubt a good PRNG could be constructed with a step operation small enough to be atomic.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to create a PRNG with a step operation that IS atomic, but you could fairly easily create one that APPEARS to be atomic, thus avoiding the costly thread locking calls. I would give an example, but PRNGs can vary too much to actually give a general example, it's a tricky thing to get lock free code going, if you already understand it, then it shouldn't be too hard to work out an implementation yourself, otherwise there is a lot of learning and trial and error before you get the hang of it and can apply one concept to a completely different algorithm

Comment: I think we're talking about different things entirely. Race conditions are a bug, even in a program to produce random output. If you want to create nondeterministic output, use a geiger counter, or something.

Comment: Yes, race conditions are a bug, but "wrapping a static synchronized class around the PRNG's calls" will cause massive speed issues, I was just saying that you could avoid race conditions via lock-free methods rather than relatively slow synchronization primitives

Answer (score 6):

> when those error's primary effects are unpredictable results and that is the point of a PRNG?

"Random" is not the same as unpredictable - Random implies a certain distribution that is very important to maintain should you want real random numbers. If your random numbers are predictable in any way it can be a security issue, or at least a program bug

Answer (score 0):

It will generally make them less deterministic (bad if you rely upon their determinism, which many people do), and may or may not make them less pseudo-random, depending upon their particular implementation details and the subtleties of how your hardware behaves.

But typically people writing multithreaded apps declare their PRNG state in TLS (thread-local-storage).  This way it doesn't matter, every thread has their own PRNG, and races won't happen unless you deliberately create them.  Not inside the PRNG code anyway.  This is lock-free and more or less full performance (depending upon TLS implementation used).