# openMP generate different random numbers with the same seed

Tags: c++, openmp, srand

I am new to openMP, in my program complex simulations are needed, to repeat the result, the seed is set for each simulation, however, when implementing openMP, different results are produced for each time I run it. so I write a simple example to check the problem as follows,
I also generated different result each time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;


int main () {

double A[10];

#pragma omp parallel for
for( int i=0;i<10;i++){
    srand(i+1);
    int m = rand()%100;
    A[i] = m;
}

cout<<"A= \n";

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    cout<<i<<" "<<A[i]<<" \n";
}
   return 0;
}
```

I run it twice, the results are:
A= 
0 86 
1 25 
2 78 
3 1 
4 46 
5 95 
6 77 
7 83 
8 15 
9 8

and 
A= 
0 15 
1 41 
2 65 
3 1 
4 75 
5 85 
6 95 
7 83 
8 74 
9 8

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rand() uses static state and is not threadsafe. You'll need to use a different, thread-safe, PRNG. See [Thread-safe random number generation for Monte-Carlo integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772100/thread-safe-random-number-generation-for-monte-carlo-integration) or [Do PRNG need to be thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616434/do-prng-need-to-be-thread-safe)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug

```
A[i] += m;
```

You're reading the prior value of `A[i]` which has never been assigned.  That's undefined behavior.  try

```
A[i] = m;
```

Then, note that the random number state might not be threadlocal.  Get a better RNG, where you have an explicit state variable instead of accessing shared global state.

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed a problem, but even I change it, the problems still exist. if I remove "#pragma omp parallel for", I can get the same result, but if I add that line, the result is different each time. more, I am not quite understand your last comments about RNG, would you mind explaining it more clearly? Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3159019: Many RNG (random number generators) are implemented as objects, and use member variables to store the seed/state instead of globals.  You need to have separate state for each thread, and the easiest way is for each thread to use its own RNG object.  The new C++11 standard defines a bunch of RNG classes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114043/random-number-generation-in-c11-how-to-generate-how-do-they-work